# how do i refactor these linq properties?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

i have 4 class properties that have similar signatures but going to different linq properties.  how do i create a delegate or something to clean this up?

for example:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DistinctUsers
    {
        get
        {
            var list = TraceLogs.OrderBy(x => x.Username).Select(x => x.Username).Distinct();
            return (from s in list select new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text = s }
           );
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DistinctMethods
    {
        get
        {
            var list = TraceLogs.OrderBy(x => x.Method).Select(x => x.Method).Distinct();
            return (from s in list select new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text = s }
           );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `TraceLogs`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want somethng like:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDistinctOrderedLogs<T>
    (Func<TraceLogs, T> extraction)
{
    return TraceLogs.OrderBy(extraction)
                    .Select(extraction)
                    .Distinct()
                    .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text = s });
}
```

Then:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DistinctMethods
{
    get { return GetDistinctOrderedLogs(t => t.Method); }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DistinctUsers
{
    get { return GetDistinctOrderedLogs(t => t.Users); }
}
```

Comment: You could also make the method generic with two generic arguments (accepting the sequence as a parameter) and simply perform an ordering, a projection, a distinct, and then a project to a `SelectListItem` for any sequence projected to any value.  There's no real dependence on the `TaceLogs` type here.